# Accessing and Reading Files Not Located in Root Folder in PHP

Tags: php

I set $userHome to C:/Users/(Users name here)/Desktop/Test

```
$userHome = realpath("./../../../../")."\\Desktop\\Test";
```

Then I get all of the names inside of the folder test inside of a array form

```
$testFolderArray = scandir($userHome);
```

Then I get the length of $testFolderArray

```
count = count($testFolderArray);
```

Then I run a for-loop for each of the folders inside of test. Inside of the for-loop it reads data.txt and properties.txt which are inside of each folder inside of the Test folder and stores content of the files inside of the two arrays.

```
for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {

$dataFile = $testFolder."/data.txt";

$propertiesFile = $testFolder."/properties.txt";


//Reads the data inside of those files
$data = file_get_contents($dataFile);
$properties = file_get_contents($propertiesFile);

$dataArray[$x] = $data;
$propertiesArray[$x] = $properties;
}
```

The error I get when I run this PHP file is:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(C:\Users\ltrujillo\Desktop\Test/TestSub/data.txt): failed to open          stream: No such file or directory i C:\Users\ltrujillo\Desktop\PHP\wamp\www\StackOverFlow_Question.php on line 30

Warning: file_get_contents(C:\Users\ltrujillo\Desktop\Test/TestSub/properties.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\ltrujillo\Desktop\PHP\wamp\www\StackOverFlow_Question.php on line 31
```

I know that the issue is that it is looking for a path that is inside of the root folder with the PHP file. So how could I change it so that it can read the context of file that is out the root folder and at the path specified?

**How to fix:**

```
for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
    if($testFolderArr[$x] == '.' || $testFolderArr[$x] == '..')
        continue; //filter . and .. directories

    $testFolder = $userHome.'\\'.$testFolderArr[$x]; 
    $dataFile = $testFolder."\\data.txt";

    $propertiesFile = $testFolder."\\properties.txt";

    if(!file_exists($dataFile) || !file_exists($propertiesFile)) 
        continue; //check for data and properties files and continue if they arent exist

    //Reads the data inside of those files
    $data = file_get_contents($dataFile);
    $properties = file_get_contents($propertiesFile);

    $dataArray[$x] = $data;
    $propertiesArray[$x] = $properties;
}
```

My issue was that I accidentally names my file data.txt and not data so the program said that the files full name was 'data.txt.txt'  which would cause a lot of errors.

Comment: I can see that you are having a windows computer. Try to change the "/properties.txt" to DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "properties.txt". This mainly because the delimiter is different on a windows computer.

Comment: Do I still leave `$testFolder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code:

```
for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {

$dataFile = $testFolder."/data.txt";

$propertiesFile = $testFolder."/properties.txt";

//Reads the data inside of those files
$data = file_get_contents($dataFile);
$properties = file_get_contents($propertiesFile);

$dataArray[$x] = $data;
$propertiesArray[$x] = $properties;
}
```

to:

```
for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
    if($testFolderArr[$x] == '.' || $testFolderArr[$x] == '..')
        continue; //filter . and .. directories

    $testFolder = $userHome.'\\'.$testFolderArr[$x]; //add this to obtain name of folder on each loop
    $dataFile = $testFolder."\\data.txt";

    $propertiesFile = $testFolder."\\properties.txt";

    if(!file_exists($dataFile) || !file_exists($propertiesFile)) 
        continue; //check for data and properties files and continue if they arent exist

    //Reads the data inside of those files
    $data = file_get_contents($dataFile);
    $properties = file_get_contents($propertiesFile);

    $dataArray[$x] = $data;
    $propertiesArray[$x] = $properties;
}
```

Comment: Could you quickly explain what I did wrong so I can prevent this from happening again?

Comment: I commented strings, that i added.
At first you not specify $testFolder variable.
Than i add check for data and properties files in each directory

Comment: It still not working I echoed $dataFile and got "./data.txt../data.txtTestSub/data.txt"

Comment: I have fixed my answer. Just add $userHome path to $testFolder variable

Comment: I am sorry to keep on bagering you with comments but not my output is C:\Users\ltrujillo\Desktop\Test/./data.txtC:\Users\ltrujillo\Desktop\Test/../data.txtC:\Users\ltrujillo\Desktop\Test/TestSub/data.txt

Comment: Just `print_r($dataArray)` and `print_r($propertiesArray)` after loop to see results.


Or if you want to `echo $dataFile` put it after if statement that i have added. (after the line with `continue;`). And it would be visual better if you will write `echo $dataFile, '<br>'`;

Comment: The issue is that there is only the folder "TestSub" in the folder "Test". This program is saying that ".." and "." are folders inside of the the folder "Test" when they clearly are not.

Comment: It's hidden system directories, that define: . - this directory, .. - parent directory, it's normal.

You can add one more if statement to remove this directories (I have added it to my post)

Comment: Now, nothing is displayed when I echo $data.

Comment: Try this. If its will not help - check if you have files data.txt and properties.txt.. then i dont know